# Converting NSPoint from window coordinates

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm overriding `draggingUpdated:` in a `WebView` subclass. This way I'm able to get the `NSPoint` where the drag destination currently is `[(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender draggingLocation]`

I want to get this `NSPoint` and "convert" it to coordinates **within** the `WebView`, and then get the underlying element at that point with `WebView`'s `elementAtPoint:`

The thing is, I got the `NSPoint`, and I also have the bounds/frame of the WebView. How is this convertible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not correct to use `-convertPointFromBase:` for this. That method is deprecated and the suggested replacement (`-convertPointFromBacking:`) is not right for this purpose because it assumes the input point is in the backing store coordinate system. (That actually gives a hint as to the original purpose of `-convertPointFromBase:`, which was part of the now-abandoned, Leopard-era attempts at high-resolution support. The "base coordinate system" it converts from was supposed to be pixel-aligned. Search for 'Pixel Alignment and Transforming View Coordinates To and From "Base" Space' in the [Leopard AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#X10_5Notes).)

You want `-convertPoint:fromView:` and you should pass `nil` for the `fromView` parameter. See [Cocoa Drawing Guide: Coordinate Systems and Transforms – Converting from Window to View Coordinates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-SW15).

Comment: I know this is old,but it's worth calling out that this also requires flipping the Y coordinate. WebView's content has a top left origin. AppKit uses bottom left.

Comment: @uchuugaka, I don't know about WebView, but the method already takes care of flipped views. The receiver knows whether it's flipped or not (and can query all of the ancestors between it and the window) and properly converts the point accordingly. The method really does what it says. It converts a point in window coordinates to a point in the view's own coordinate system.

Comment: @KenThomases You're amazing and always on! WebView is not flipped, but the coordinates in DOM scripts are!

Answer (score 0):

OK, wow. Just came across one of those cases where Cocoa seems to be absolutely amazing :

```
[self convertPointFromBase:point];
```

Yep, that's all it took.

Comment: Old post but still, that's not nice. Besides, convertPointFromBase is deprecated. Ken's answer is more correct.